# JQuery Carousel blinks when I click on next or prev links

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm creating a carousel to display a custom post type. The loop is working fine, and i managed to get the layout exactly the way that I wanted. But, when the user clicks on the next/prev links, after the transition the carousel blinks out, and then pops up again.

Here is the link for the live demo: https://goace.vc/teste-exits/

The carousel code:

```
        <div id="exits" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

              <?php
              $current = 0;

              if( $exits->have_posts() ): while( $exits->have_posts() ) : $exits->the_post();

                if ($current == 0) {
                  $exitStatus = 'active';
                } else {
                  $exitStatus = '';
                }
                ?>

                <?php if ($current % 2 === 0) { ?>
                  <div class="item <?=$exitStatus?>">
                <?php } ?>


                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="exit-box">
                      <div class="col-xs-7">
                        <div class="exit-img" style="background-image: url('https://goace.vc/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/0028_Fundacity.png')"></div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-5 exit-details">
                        <h3><?= get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p><?= the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        <hr class="half-line">
                        <?php
                          $tipoExit = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'tipo_exit', array("fields" => "names"));
                          $anoExit = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'ano_do_exit', array("fields" => "names"));
                        ?>
                        <p><small>Exit: <b><?= $tipoExit[0] ?></b><br>Ano: <b><?= $anoExit[0] ?></b></small></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <?php
                    $current++;
                    if ($current % 2 === 0) {
                  ?>
                    </div>
                  <?php } ?>

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

              </div>
                <a data-slide="prev" href="#exits" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
                <a data-slide="next" href="#exits" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
              </div>
```

Any ideas of what is causing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show all code that is relevant to the `in_progress` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally code would be best. By inspecting the site however, the class `slider` seems to refresh the carousel when it slides, it adds the `in_progress` class which sets this behavior.

You can remove the class `slide` from the element `<div id="exits" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">`

to:

```
<div id="exits" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
```

This will stop the blinking but will remove the slider effect (images will still switch but without the visual effect). If you share the relevant code we could try to solve it from there.

Comment: You can remove the class `slide`... Not `slider`. ;) Great catch!

Comment: That stops the blinking... But also removes the movement effect... Let see what OP will think of it...  (I tested it by directly typing `$("#exits").removeClass("slide");` in console.)

Comment: Removing the class has really worked, thanks! I updated the question with the code.

Comment: Ronaldo, not sure that php would help, thanks though. I would search for the class in_progress inside of some js file for the slide effect. Seems related to a display:none/block toggle. Also in_progress on the slide css file could work as well, it may have display:none; which you could try switch to block and tweak from there.

Comment: @Syden, I tried the `.in_progress { display: block; }` and did not work. But thanks anyway! I noticed that the "blink" only happens when I click the arrows, when the slide is trigered by the timer it works fine. There maybe some other script in some plugin that is causing this. I'll look for that problem.

Comment: Ronaldo, any further help please let me know, so far with that code doesn't seem to help much. Just in case, make sure to try `.in_progress { display: block !important;}`, in case it's being overridden. Good luck!

Comment: The problem ended up by be the class "next left", that is added during the transition. That class has a 'position: absolute' that was causing the damage. I used a `.active { position: relative !important; }`, and solved it! Thanks for all your help!